# Create table with unique column changes sort order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create dictionary table which has only two columns PK Id and unique name:

```
CREATE TABLE [SnApp].[DictionaryErrorType]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT UC_Name UNIQUE ([Name]),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ID_DictionaryErrorType] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

Inserting values:

```
INSERT INTO [SnApp].[DictionaryErrorType] (Name) 
VALUES ('Info'), ('Warning'), ('Error')
```

After doing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [SnApp].[DictionaryErrorType]
```

[I got output sorted by Name not by primary key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f6zs.png)

Why ?

How can I have only this two columns but sorted by ID not by name ?

Comment: Any ordering you see in a select that doesn't have a `ORDER BY` is an illusion that can be broken by a butterfly flapping its wings.

Comment: If you **don't explicitly specify** an `ORDER BY` clause - ***there IS no ordering!*** - if you need an order, then use `ORDER BY` .....

Answer (score 3):

Data in a sql server table isn't inherently ordered. It just exists.

To get the correct order, use `ORDER BY`

```
select * 
from [SnApp].[DictionaryErrorType]
order by ID
```

Comment: I know i can use Order by clause. That is not an issue here. I'm trying to order data without this clause.
If I wouldn't add Unique on Name column then data would be sorted by ID

Comment: Like I said, the rows are not stored in order. It **must** be defined in the query.

Comment: But if query doesn't define sort order then SQL returns data sorted by ID or in this case Name column. Why ? Isnt there any flag which defines this ?

Comment: @AdamN Please understand... **The rows are stored with no order**. If you do not define an `order by`, there is no default order. This is how the product works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly mention order by clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM [SnApp].[DictionaryErrorType]
    ORDER BY Id
```

If you have clustered ascending index sometimes by default it returns in sorted order but you cannot guarantee sorted results there